# what it difficult about this suspect

Tags: adverbs, gerunds

a. What is difficult about this suspect is to gain information.

b. What is difficult about this suspect is to gain information about him.

c. What is difficult about this suspect is gaining information.

d. What is difficult about this suspect is gaining information about him.

I think the 'about him' at the end is necessary. I find (a) and (c) incorrect.

Am I right?

Many thanks

Comment: d. is correct and natural, b. is grammatical, but unnatural. The other two are incorrect.

When we say "gain information", we do not automatically infer it means about that suspect. Without "about him", it means to gather information *in general*.

Comment: None of them sound very natural to me. It might sound better in context though: e.g. if there is parallelism with the preceding sentence. I can't imagine saying this on its own.

Comment: Honestly, it is difficult to answer this question, because none of the sentences sounds natural.  "gaining information" is not something "about this suspect".  A more natural phrasing would be "It is difficult to gain information about this suspect".